# Last value from mySQL in python (Query)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, raspberry-pi

Trying to get the last value from MySQL on Raspberry Pi. No idea why my simple code wont work, gives error at "execute() first" at row = cursor.fetchone().

Here is my code:

```
# External module imports
import time
import os
import datetime
import MySQLdb

# Connect to mysql
db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost","zikmir","gforce","temp_database")
# Prepair a cursor    
cursor=db.cursor()

# Select three columns, id, time and temp from table time_temp
cursor.execute = ("SELECT id, time, temp FROM time_temp")
# ID is autoincremented value, time is in TIME and temp is float 

row = cursor.fetchone()
# Trying to store the last result in variable row

# Close cursor and database
cursor.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: Looks correct: It will fail however if there is no data in the table time_temp

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I do have data in the table, I'm pushing data and also fetching it successfully at my website in php. www.ziks.ca

Answer (score 1):

watch the `=` in`cursor.execute = ("SELECT id, time, temp FROM time_temp")`. It should read `cursor.execute("SELECT...")`